# Is there a reason for this behavior of the filter object in Python?

Tags: python, function, filter, behavior

```py
>>> a = filter(lambda x: x&1, [1,2])
>>> list(a)
[2]
>>> list(a)
[]
```

It's quite counter intuitive, isn't it? So if anyone has an explanation for why it is like that, feel free!

I am using Python 3.8.2 by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you knew to wrap the result of the call to `filter` with `list()`, I am assuming you are familiar with the concept of generator functions and its ilk. The `filter` function returns actually something similar to a generator function in that it can only be iterated once. See below:

```
>>> a = filter(lambda x: x^1, [1,2])
>>> type(a)
<class 'filter'>
>>> it = iter(a)
>>> next(it)
2
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> it = iter(a) # try to iterate the filter a second time
>>> next(it) # you will get a StopIteration exception the very first time
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>>
```

The above code is essentially equivalent to:

```
a = filter(lambda x: x^1, [1,2])
print(type(a))
for item in a:
    print(item)
for item in a:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

a is an iterable, the items of which have been consumed the first time you called list(a). Subsequent list(a) will get nothing.

Similarly,

```
a = (i for i in range(10))
list(a)
[0, 1....10]
list(a)
[]
```

I prefer C# behavior that has distinct IEnumerable and IEnumerator interfaces.